# Modifying SVG files flutter

Tags: flutter, svg

I have an svg file of the human body with groups of traces made for each muscle. I'd like to make a function that highlights certain muscles. Using regex is not the right way to go. I tried using xml but I'm not sure how to do it the right way and I'm not sure if xml truly is the right way.

This is the structure of my svg file:

```
<svg>
  <g id="Muscles" transform="translate(-0.146 0.364)">
    <g id="Abdominals">
      <path id="path196" d="M3294.281-2851.382c-15.892,20.521-35.62,44.154-48.66,64.122,0,0,31.81-113.859-15.028-518.839,0,0,65.728,78.144,94.49,251.4,0,0,10.452,150.03-30.8,203.315" transform="translate(-1825.079 4663.033)" fill="#95999f"/>
      <path id="path234" d="M3671.994-2915.5c15.893,20.542,35.6,44.178,48.659,64.119,0,0-23.994-49.737,22.844-454.717,0,0-65.7,78.144-94.491,251.4,0,0-18.265,85.908,22.988,139.2" transform="translate(-1494.489 4663.033)" fill="#95999f"/>
    </g>
    ...
    ...
    <g id="Triceps">
      <path id="path198" d="M3172.882-3654.165s-144.517,96.743-129.823,251.042c14.692,154.272,59.807,225.4,10.234,308.571,0,0,127.978-21.957,152.021-141.282,24.066-119.325-28.764-221.175-32.433-418.331" transform="translate(-1975.527 4385.352)" fill="#95999f"/>
      <path id="path236" d="M3832.757-3654.165s144.494,96.743,129.8,251.042c-14.694,154.272-59.806,225.4-10.236,308.571,0,0-127.952-21.957-152.02-141.282s28.787-221.175,32.456-418.331" transform="translate(-1375.567 4385.352)" fill="#95999f"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I'm trying to change the color of a given muscles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do that:

```js
let abd = document.getElementById("Abdominals").getElementsByTagName("path")
for (let path of abd) {
  path.setAttribute("fill", "red");
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="1066.48291015625 731.18701171875 1521.556640625 1144.586181640625" version="1.1" >
  <g id="Muscles" transform="translate(-0.146 0.364)">
    <g id="Abdominals">
      <path id="path196" d="M3294.281-2851.382c-15.892,20.521-35.62,44.154-48.66,64.122,0,0,31.81-113.859-15.028-518.839,0,0,65.728,78.144,94.49,251.4,0,0,10.452,150.03-30.8,203.315" transform="translate(-1825.079 4663.033)" fill="#95999f"/>
      <path id="path234" d="M3671.994-2915.5c15.893,20.542,35.6,44.178,48.659,64.119,0,0-23.994-49.737,22.844-454.717,0,0-65.7,78.144-94.491,251.4,0,0-18.265,85.908,22.988,139.2" transform="translate(-1494.489 4663.033)" fill="#95999f"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Triceps">
      <path id="path198" d="M3172.882-3654.165s-144.517,96.743-129.823,251.042c14.692,154.272,59.807,225.4,10.234,308.571,0,0,127.978-21.957,152.021-141.282,24.066-119.325-28.764-221.175-32.433-418.331" transform="translate(-1975.527 4385.352)" fill="#95999f"/>
      <path id="path236" d="M3832.757-3654.165s144.494,96.743,129.8,251.042c-14.694,154.272-59.806,225.4-10.236,308.571,0,0-127.952-21.957-152.02-141.282s28.787-221.175,32.456-418.331" transform="translate(-1375.567 4385.352)" fill="#95999f"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

It's the easiest way e.g. to get your path elements via their IDs and then change their attributes as usual. You don't have to change attributes of all path children elements of your groups since you retrieve their entire collection etc.